# Sublime text opens an xml file in HEX view

Tags: conversion, sublime-text-2, xml, hexadecimal

I have an [xml file](http://www13.zippyshare.com/v/1FYv0x5G/file.html)(rename to .xml) and I need to open this in Sublime text. But if I try to open and view it, it displays the data in Hexadecimal values. But I want this to be displayed in xml format. But If I view other xml files its opening normally.

The data is displayed as:

```
ef03 0000 0f00 0000 1500 0000 6200 6900
7a00 2e00 6200 6f00 6b00 6800 6f00 7200
7300 7400 2e00 7800 7000 7200 6900 7600
6100 6300 7900 0000 0100 0000 e00f 0000
0000 0000 0100 0000 2100 0000 6200 6900
7a00 2e00 6200 6f00 6b00 6800 6f00 7200
....
....
0000 0000 0000 0000
```

How can I open and analyse this file in sublime text editor? Is there any shortcut or menu option to convert this?

UPDATE:

After selecting `File > Reopen with Encoding > UTF-16 LE` as suggested in the comments the file now is partially visible with NULL text inbetween the text which is not copiable(posted as a screenshot below),

[image: Screenshot_sublime_encodign]

Comment: Can you verify with a different text editor that this file contains XML?

Comment: @NonlinearFruit In Notepad++ also some unreadable text followed by bunch of NULL values are displayed. Is there any way to convert these hexadecimal values to xml or anyother human readable format.?

Comment: With this file in ST2, try **File** > **Reopen with Encoding** and try each of those.  If you're *lucky*, one of those might fix it.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Thats partially readable but with `|NULL|` values filled within the text which are non-copiable.

Comment: Is `UTF-16 LE` the only encoding that halfway worked?

Comment: Yes..All other formats are totally unreadable..